# Convert Same Table Nested Query to JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

We have to query on same table. Table 'Foo', structure is like this,

```
Foo
-------------
ID  MID  AID STATUS
1   12   88  A
2   12   88  B
3   13   88  A
4   13   88  B
5   14   88  A
6   15   88  A
```

So We need only those records who have STATUS = A but not STATUS != B. We successfully created nested query. But this table contains million records and its consuming too much time.

Working Nested Query

```
SELECT FO.MID FROM FOO FO WHERE FO.AID = 188 AND FO.STATUS = 'A' AND FO.MID NOT IN 
(SELECT FO.MID FROM FOO FO WHERE FO.AID = 188 AND FO.STATUS = 'B' AND FO.MID IS NOT NULL)
```

So how to make this fast using JOIN?

Comment: what does explain say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is aggregation:

```
select fo.mid
from foo fo
group by fo.mid
having sum(fo.status = 'A') > 0 and
       sum(fo.status = 'B') = 0;
```

If you have a table of `mid`, then perhaps the best method is:

```
select m.mid
from mids m
where exists (select 1 from foo where fo.mid = m.mid and fo.status = 'A') and
      not exists (select 1 from foo where fo.mid = m.mid and fo.status = 'B');
```

For performance for this query, you want an index on `foo(mid, status)`.

Answer (score 1):

I you have an index on MID, then the below query may help.

```
SELECT FO.MID 
FROM FOO FO 
WHERE FO.AID = 88 AND FO.STATUS = 'A' AND 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM FOO f WHERE fo.MID=f.MID AND F.STATUS = 'B')
```